# How to create a combination table from a single table MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, combinations, permutation

So I have this following table *options* lets say it contains three columns :

```
--------------------------
--------- options --------
--------------------------
  id  |  name |  category
--------------------------
  1   |  blue |    1
  2   |  red  |    1
  3   |  a    |    2
  4   |  b    |    2
  5   |  c    |    2
  6   |  99   |    3
--------------------------
```

Now, I already have the following query to create a table containing three columns as a combination from table above :

```
SELECT T1.name, T2. name, T3.name 
FROM (options T1 JOIN options T2 ON (T1.name > T2.name AND T1.category != T2.category)) 
LEFT JOIN options T3 
ON (T3.name < T2.name AND T3.name < T1.name AND T3.category != T1.category AND T3.category != T2.category);
```

The results from running above query will return the following table (**which is** **incorrect**):

```
--------------------------
------ combinations ------
--------------------------
  name  |  name |  name
--------------------------
  blue  |   a   |    99
  red   |   a   |    99
  blue  |   b   |    99
  red   |   b   |    99
  blue  |   c   |    99
  red   |   c   |    99
  red   |   99  |   NULL
  blue  |   99  |   NULL
  a     |   99  |   NULL
  b     |   99  |   NULL
  c     |   99  |   NULL
--------------------------
```

**The resulting table should look as follows:**

```
--------------------------
------ combinations ------
--------------------------
  name  |  name |  name
--------------------------
  blue  |   a   |    99
  red   |   a   |    99
  blue  |   b   |    99
  red   |   b   |    99
  blue  |   c   |    99
  red   |   c   |    99
--------------------------
```

The problem is whenever there is 3 different categories in the options the combination will also return the third name column including *NULL* values, and we don't want that.

I want the resulting *combinations* table to always have 3 column, and if there is only one category only populates the first column in the *combinations* table (the other columns should be null in this case), if there is two the first two columns as combinations (3rd column will be null), and if its three, all three columns have to have values respective to the *options* table (no null values).

Comment: So your sample data set isn't really representative?

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean by sample data being representative?

Comment: It doesn't identify the edge cases

Comment: @Strawberry it does, its actually an edge case itself, compare the expected result table with the actual result I posted

Comment: But there are no nulls in your desired result

Comment: Perhaps you haven't explained the problem very well

Comment: @Strawberry exactly, the results should not contain any null columns in case that there are 3 categories. The problem is well explained, make sure you read all of the details correctly (I agree its a confusing situation)

Comment: Oh I did. I note you have lengthy comments at the bottom of the answer provided too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cross join`:

```
select *
from (select name
      from options
      where category = 1
     ) n1 cross join
     (select name
      from options
      where category = 2
     ) n2 cross join
     (select name
      from options
      where category = 3
     ) n3
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works in the case that we have 3 categories and we know their ID's, lets assume that we don't know how many categories will be but its maximum three categories (anywhere from 1 to 3 distinct category IDs), and also we do not know the category ID's. can you explain a solution using this constraints?

Comment: @zzzzakhar77 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.